# Copy a bigquery table while streaming data is still in buffer

Tags: google-bigquery, streaming

If I copy a BigQuery table while the streaming data is still in buffer, will I get the full set of data in the copied table? Or will I lose data which is still in buffer?

I coded to copy a table while the data streaming is still in process. But I don't know if the copied table will get the full set of data because of not knowing when the data streaming is finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data in streaming buffer is available for Querying only.
If you copy or export table - data in buffer will be "lost" in target

Comment: Thanks, so in other words, instead of using copy table. I could use
1) create a new table
2) select from old table and insert to new table

This way, even the old table data is still in streaming, I will not lose any data in the new table?

Comment: formally - above is correct - note: you will pay for whole table scan.

Comment: Thanks. My data is huge enough needed to be run on BigQuery. But it is small enough that I don't have to worry about the scan cost. :)

But for the knowledge, will it be cheaper if I stream data to two tables than I stream data to one table and then copy (or select insert) data to the second table?

Comment: just compare prices for streaming vs. querying :o)

Answer (score 1):

just adding this answer here because maybe @searain comment not visible for everyone, but the solution to this problem is:

instead of running a copy job to copy the table. You can run this query to do the copying:

```
CREATE TABLE {destinationTableName} As SELECT * FROM {sourceTableName}
```

and as @Mikhail mentioned buffer data is available for Querying only, then this query will copy all data.